# Navigation Bar and Status Bar does not hide

Tags: android, user-interface, system

I have this code for showing and hiding the status bar and navigation bar

```
private void hideSystemUI() {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN 
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
    }


private void showSystemUI() {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }
```

Sadly this results in a white nav bar and a none transparent status bar when I call hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this to your show method

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

And this to your hide method

```
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```